# Azure subscription for Office365 API

Tags: office365, azure

I have an active **Office365** account. I want to use o365 APIs for my project.

My question is, Do I must have a **Azure subscription** to access o365 application's API?

Comment: No, Azure is separate from Office 365

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. Actually I got confused after read this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666233/get-started-with-office-365-rest-api